# MySQL Query is updating the database BUT NOT the DataGridView control?

Tags: mysql, vb.net-2010

I've been studying and trying to teach myself VB.net coding and MySQL from this site: http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/vbnet-mysql-tutorials/the-vbnet-mysql-tutorial-part-4

Thus far I've been successful in grasping all the concepts and following along the code, however, I'm running into a problem with the query I'm calling on one of my buttons.  I'm not getting an error - as I would expect - and it appears the query is updating the database appropriately (this is because I can log into the database and see the entries).

The problem is that the when I call the .Refresh method on the DataGridView control, the content from the database isn't being pulled in.

Is this an error with the query or is it something else?

Here's the entire code of the form (frmMain):

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Data


Public Class frmMain

Private myConnString As String
Private myUserID As Integer

Public WriteOnly Property connectionString() As String
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        myConnString = value
    End Set
End Property

Public WriteOnly Property UserID() As Integer
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        myUserID = value
    End Set
End Property


Private Sub cmdRefresh_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdRefresh.Click

    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
    Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim myData As New DataTable
    Dim SQL As String

    SQL = "SELECT CONCAT(u.lastname, ', ', u.firstname) AS Name, s.message AS Message, " _
        & "DATE_FORMAT(e.timestamp, '%b %d %Y - %r') AS 'Date & Time', e.status AS Status " _
        & "FROM event e LEFT JOIN status s ON e.message_id = s.message_id, user u " _
        & "WHERE(e.user_id = u.user_id) " _
        & "AND event_id IN( " _
        & "SELECT MAX(e.event_id) " _
        & "FROM event e " _
        & "GROUP BY e.user_id) " _
        & "ORDER BY Name"

    conn.ConnectionString = myConnString

    Try
        conn.Open()
        Try
            myCommand.Connection = conn
            myCommand.CommandText = SQL
            myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
            myAdapter.Fill(myData)
            dgvStatus.DataSource = myData
            dgvStatus.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells
            dgvStatus.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells
        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error reading from the database: " & vbCrLf & myerror.Message)
        End Try
    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Error Connecting to Database: " & vbCrLf & myerror.Message)
    Finally
        If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
            conn.Close()
        End If
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    cboStatus.Items.Add("In")
    cboStatus.Items.Add("Out")
    cboStatus.SelectedIndex = 0

    dgvStatus.ReadOnly = True

    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
    Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim myData As New DataTable
    Dim SQL As String

    SQL = "SELECT s.message_id, s.message " _
        & "FROM tutorial.status s " _
        & "WHERE user_id IS NULL and deleted = 'False'"

    conn.ConnectionString = myConnString

    Try
        conn.Open()
        Try
            myCommand.Connection = conn
            myCommand.CommandText = SQL
            myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
            myAdapter.Fill(myData)
            cboMessage.DataSource = myData
            cboMessage.DisplayMember = "message"
            cboMessage.ValueMember = "message_id"
        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error reading from the database: " & vbCrLf & myerror.Message)
        End Try
    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Error Connecting to Database: " & vbCrLf & myerror.Message)
    Finally
        If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
            conn.Close()
        End If
    End Try


End Sub

Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdUpdate.Click
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand

    conn.ConnectionString = myConnString

    myCommand.Connection = conn
    myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO event(user_id, message_id, timestamp, status, creator)" _
        & "VALUES(?UserID, ?MessageID, NOW(), ?Status, ?Creator);"
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?UserID", myUserID)
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?MessageID", cboMessage.SelectedValue)
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Status", cboStatus.SelectedItem)
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Creator", myUserID)

    Try
        conn.Open()
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("There was an error updating the database: " & vbCrLf & myerror.Message)
    Finally
        If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
            conn.Close()
        End If
    End Try

    cmdRefresh.PerformClick()

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-bind the datasource. After:

```
dgvStatus.DataSource = myData
```

put

```
dgvStatus.ResetBindings()
```

Comment: Thanks for you response.  Unfortunately, it appears there isn't a .DataBind() property on the control.  The only property that comes close is .DataBindings() but that throws an error.

Comment: I apologize. I was thinking GridView, not DataGridView. Try `ResetBindings` instead. Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, but I think I figured out the problem.  While instantiating frmMain, I neglected to add a line that passed the UserID parameter from the login form.  I was missing this:              mainForm.UserID = UserID

Answer (score 0):

It appears I solved my own problem.  While instantiating my main form (frmMain), I neglected one line of code that was intended to pass the UserID parameter from the Login form (frmLogin) to the main form.

I inserted the following line:

```
mainForm.UserID = UserID
```

Thanks again.